# MD5 or SHA hash of a large file in Java

Tags: java, hash, md5, sha

I need to calculate SHA or MD5 hash of a large file. The thing I need to do is this,I make an example:

Suppose I have a 1GB file.
To calculate the hash I want to divide this file in 4 parts of 256MB(I want to divide it in smaller parts).

1)start to calculate the hash of the first part

2)get the output hash of the first part,give it in input with the second part and calculate the hash of the second part

3)get the output hash of the 2) point,give it in input with the third part and calculate the hash of the third part

4)get the output hash of the 3) point,give it in input with the fourth part and calculate the hash of the entire file.

I searched a lot on google but I haven't found nothing similar.I read that with MessageDigest by using the method update I can read file chunks until the  entire file is loaded and then calculate the hash but I haven't understood if when I load a chunk it calculate also the hash of it(so it would be good in my case) or if it's only a loading and  the hash is calculated at the end when the file is entirely loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also want to look at `java.security.DigestInputStream` to calculate the hash of the whole file.

If you need intermediate hashes for the parts, you may have luck with `java.security.MessageDigest.clone()`; after a part clone the MessageDigest instance used for the hash calculation and call `digest()` on the clone to get the hash value after the part.

The original MessageDigest instance can be updated with the bytes of the next part.

Comment: mmm but in this way when I update the MessageDigest with the next part and then use digest() method it will recalculate the hash also by reading the previous part right? 
I don't want that it have to calculate the hash by reading again the previous part.

Comment: I want that if for example the file is divided in two chunk the hash of the entire file works in this way:

1)I want to calculate the hash of the first part
2)I want to calculate the hash of the second part(first + second) by reading only the second part basing on the output of the first part

Comment: That's exactly what this does. The first result is h(p1), the second h(p1+p2), ... You use the same MessageDigest instance for the updates; the clones are only used to make the digest() calls. This is necessary because a digest() call finishes the hash by doing some padding of the last block. You can't update after a digest call.